# Training Time for Eigenfaces using Opencv c++

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm currently training a database of Eigenfaces using Opencv. I have 50 persons in my database with 250 pictures each, and I use all Eigenfaces and its been 2 days since I started training and it still is not finished. How long should I still wait? and is 250 for each person too much?

Any information will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to process 12500 images using PCA ? And I suspect the images are in color and large resolution. It really too many for standard OpenCV's PCA and any closed form PCA. You can try to use smaller number of samples per person or use iterative PCA methods, or better use other features extractor.

In classical examples was used AT face dataset with 10 samples per person: [example](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) and as I remember, there are 40 persons in that DS.